# play! framework 2.0 crud module

Tags: java, frameworks, playframework-2.0, crud

Im using play 2.0.1 to build my application. Also Im  using Ebean for the backend layer and mysql as a database so far. Java as the language.

Question:

Isn't there a CRUD module (dynamic) or a crud creation module? I looked on the internet and it is very hard to find something regarding the new play framework 2.x.

According to this thread there is none ... [[play-framework] [2.0] CRUD Administration](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/0g7YhdzA6Fs/xXSoW25X4ekJ) .

But some of the answers are old. Maybe something is in the pipeline?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing planned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no crud in play 2.
Here are your options:

- Sample Code.
  The samples like "ZenTasks" for front end, "Computer Database" for backend, and "Forms" for form stuff contain example code that can be quickly manipulated.  Not as nice as real crud but you take what you can get.
  http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Samples
- glitter8.  Current recommendations from forums are to use glitter8.  See this as an example of a play specific crud replacement
  https://github.com/k33g/play-java-lazy.g8
- cato-crud-generator.  I noticed this.  Could check it out: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/crud-forms-play-framework-2-cato-crud-generator

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented [this](https://github.com/hakandilek/play2-crud) simple CRUD library for Play2. You can extend generic DAO objects from the library, and pass them to generic CRUD or API (JSON) controllers. You only need to write the template code which is quite easy if you manipulate them from the examples. Also works quite well with Guice injectors.

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried for Simple CRUD Play Application.

I have created Student CRUD.

You can find it [Here](https://mahendrabagul@bitbucket.org/mahendrabagul/final-demo.git)